# GoogleMaps.animateCamera crashes with Firebase Realtime Database code

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

```
ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startLocationLatLng).title("Start Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))));
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finishLocationLatLng).title("Finish Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))));

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : markers) {

                builder.include(marker.getPosition());

            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int padding = 300;
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);

            mMap.animateCamera(cu);

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                    .child("users").child(uId).child("CurrentChallenge")
                    .child("Active").setValue("1");
```

App crashes after setting value of child "Active" in Firebase, but error is:
*Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int): Map size can't be 0. Most likely, layout has not yet occured for the map view.*
When I remove part of setting value - all works fine.
Can't understand why this error occures, I've tried to create AsyncTask for setting value, also tried to paste this code in animateCamera-onFinish callback, always the same error.

***UPD:** this is a bit wierd, becose code works after replacing **newLatLngBounds** construction, with simple:

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16.0f));
```

But this code animate map only to one location, without possibility to see both markers.
Any thoughts? This is something with threads? I have no idea how can this be linked (**LatLngBounds** and **FirebaseDatabase**).